# Changing Xcode project types on an existing project

Tags: macos, xcode5

I started a project as a command line utility, but realized afterwards that I'd like basic wrapper functionality like an icon and the ability to bundle an icon. It's not a complex project so I could simply re-created it, but this seems like something I should know...

Can you change a project type in Xcode after it's started? The differences between the types are relatively limited, is it something you can do manually with a few settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. 
No in that there is not a function in Xcode to just change it.

The project types are just templates of files and build settings pre configured for common needs. 
So, Yes, you can modify the project. Make it match the delta between a command line tool template and an app template. 
That can be a lot of work and there's a lot to miss. 
The simplest thing to do is to create a new project and copy files to it.